# ruby, enable chat between two users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am on RoR and I would like to know if anyone can explain how I can create a system which displays a button for sending a message invitation to an other user.

If I havn't send invitation, then the button should be "Send invitation", else the button should be "Remove invitation".

I have created a messaging system that allows communication between all users of my website.I also have created an notification system which help them send notification to users.

I have a MVC application for my "send_invitation" system but not sure how to create a method which will send notification to other user. And also to ensure that when the user accepts the request, they should be allowed to exchange messages. I want a clarification on the above process.

Comment: create a column in your table called 'invitation_flag'. Set it to default FALSE. If user clicks on "send Invitation" set the flag value to TRUE. When Displaying the button, check if 'invitation_flag' is true, display the "Remove invitation" button, else if 'invitation_flag' is true, display the "Send invitation" button

Comment: a column in what table ??

Comment: 'send_invitation' table

Comment: okay, so invitation_flag is a boolean ?

Comment: Yes, it must be Boolean